# Mapbox : Can't load features (markers) by map_id

Tags: mapbox

When i try to load markers from my map i get this error message:

```
{"message":"Markers do not exist"}
```

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>BoxMap</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />


<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'this_is_my_token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([40.447, -5.625], 2);

L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/this_is_my_style').addTo(map);

L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadID('this_is_my_map_id').addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: when i try to put a map_id from the given examples on mapbox website, it works! example: examples.map-h61e8o8e

Thanks

Comment: Please format the error and code.  And  do provide some context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's done. Any idea?